# android-adding tabs in view flipper

Tags: android, tabs, viewflipper

I am developing an android application in which I have creted a TabActivity. For each tab I am using a separate activity and a separate layout file. Actually this activity is a details screen which shows customer information. The user can click on an item in a listview activity in order to see customer's detailed info in the tab acticity. There he can use navigation buttons to navigate through the customers In a few words, if the listview displays 10 records and the user clicks on the first item the customer details.tabactivity opens and displays detailed info. Using the navigation butons the user can see the next or previous record.

Now, I would like to use a viewflipper in the details screen in order to use animations while navigating through the records and in the end. to use fling gestures instead of buttons. Nevertheless I haven't found a proper example of how to add a tabhost/tabactivity in the flipper. I also thought to create the tabs using one layout in order to add it to the viewflipper but then I have no way to create the tabs inside the activity that hosts the viewfliper.

Any help would be apreciated. Thank you in advance.

ps. I will create a basic app of what I am talking and upload if that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) may be more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: What if one does not want to use Fragments?

Comment: Then you don't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710561/can-i-use-view-pager-with-views-not-with-fragments