# Viewpager out of memory?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view, android-pageradapter

First of all I do not get any error. My problem is that I do not see the pages 2&3 (out of 4) in the ViewPager. Let me explain:

First all I add directly the pages inside the layout without fragments:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/drawerPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/page_start_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        //3 textviews, 1 imageview
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/page_start_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        //1 textview, 1 imageview
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/page_start_three"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        //1 textview, 1 imageview
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/page_start_four"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        //3 textviews, 1 button
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I do so for simplicity. Now I load the pager adapter to the activity:

```
WizardPagerAdapter adapter = new WizardPagerAdapter();
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.drawerPager);
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And of course define `WizardPagerAdapter`. You will see below that `destroyItem()` does nothing and `instantiateItem()` just returns the view with is found by the id. This is the code I based from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710611/1447885) :

```
class WizardPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public RelativeLayout instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        System.out.println(position);
        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.id.page_start_one;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.id.page_start_two;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.id.page_start_three;
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.id.page_start_four;
            break;
        }

        return (RelativeLayout) findViewById(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }
}
```

As I said before, with this code I can only see the equivalent RelativeLayouts in pages 0 & 1 but the pages 2 & 3 are always empty.

- Do you know why this is happening?
- Is it because of memory limitation?
- Or another assumption I have is pages 2 & 3 have never been inflated, since onCreate `instantiateItem()` run only for the first two. (snitched by `System.out.println(position);` which prints 0 & 1).

Answer (score 0):

It's probly because viewpager only caches 2 pages by default

you can change it with:  `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(X);`

where 'X' is the amount of pages.