# Support multiple webviews in one activity

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to display multiple webviews in one activity but only one shows up at a time.

Here is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_showdata"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.rober.******.showdata">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/amazon_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/homedepot_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="186dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/target_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/homedepot_product"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/lowes_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/target_product"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/meijer_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amazon_product"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/walmart_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/meijer_product"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the main.java file

```
if (amazonproduct != null) {
                WebView wview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.amazon_product);
                wview.loadData(amazonproduct, "text/html", null);
                Log.i("amazonproduct", "vaild info");
            }
            else {
                WebView wview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.amazon_product);
                wview.loadData("<p> Product Not Found On Amazon</p>", "text/html", null);
                Log.i("amazonproduct", " invalid vaild info");
            }

            if (walmartproduct != null) {
                WebView wview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.walmart_product);
                wview2.loadData(walmartproduct, "text/html", null);
                Log.i("walmartproduct", "vaild info");
            }
            else {
                WebView wview2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.walmart_product);
                wview2.loadData("<p> Product Not Found On Walmart</p>", "text/html", null);
                Log.i("amazonproduct", " invalid vaild info");
            }
```

As I stated above, only 1 view shows up. Is the error in my .xml or my java activity?

Comment: `wrap_content` for sizing will not work well. Plus, six `WebView` widgets will result in none of them being usable, as they will be far too small.

Comment: Stick them in a viewpager, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710561/can-i-use-view-pager-with-views-not-with-fragments

Comment: @CommonsWare what would you suggest for sizing?

Comment: One at a time, such as via the `ViewPager` that petey suggests.