# How to change RecyclerView LayoutManager from List to Grid?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

I'm using a ViewPager in which I have a RecyclerView, in this RecyclerView I want to change the LayoutManager from List to Grid.

I've implemented this code:

```
 void setLManager(boolean managerL){
    GridLayoutManager glManager = new GridLayoutManager(viewPager.getContext(), 2);
      if (mData.size() % 2 != 0) {
          final int item = mData.size() - 1;
          glManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
              @Override
              public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                  return position == item ? 2 : 1;
              }
          });
      }
    LinearLayoutManager lLManager = new LinearLayoutManager(viewPager.getContext());

    recycler.setLayoutManager(managerL ? lLManager : glManager);
    sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recycler.setAdapter(sAdapter);
}
```

On the RecyclerView's onCreateViewHolder I have the following code:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;

        int layout = 0;

        if(viewType == Util.LIST){

            layout = R.layout.item_list;

        }else {

            layout = R.layout.item_grid;

        }
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder; 
}
```

I make the change from List to Grid through a FloatingButton, changing the value of "managerL" (this is a boolean variable) so, when I press the button, the layouts change (from R.layout.item_list to R.layout_grid and vice versa), but the layout manager still showing the LinearLayoutManager.

I'd like to know, why isn't my RecyclerViewManager changing?

Comment: I think once the adapter has made a ViewHolder, you cannot replace the view. You need to replace the entire adapter. Edit: You might get away with just setting the same adapter again!

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Do you put `recycler.setLayoutManager(managerL ? lLManager : glManager);` in your FloatingButton clickEvent ?

Comment: Is your 1st block of code in `onCreate`?

Comment: @huang12345 yes, I put my recycler.setLayoutManager(managerL ? lLManager : glManager); in a function and this function is called in the FloatingButton clickEvent, this is my floatingButton code:

Comment: fbListGrid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                switchViewList = !switchViewList;
                sAdapter.toggleItemViewType();
                setLManager(switchViewList);
            }
        });

Comment: I think you need either 2 adapters (1 for each view type) or for simplicity 2 RVs (that you show/hide). I don't think there's any way to tell 1 adapter to remake the Views/ViewHolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem I had in my code and with this, I found a solution, the problem was in the adapter of my ViewPager, and I found the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710611

The reason why my RecyclerView didn't change from LayoutManager, was that in my ViewPager adapter it showed the RecyclerView layout with a LayoutInflater, and for some reason this made my RecyclerView not make the change from list to grid, in the link I left above, there is a better way to create the adapter for the ViewPager and it was the one that worked for me.